# We are using a android SDK for payment.That sdk changes colorPrimaryDark to red. After payment status bar remains red instead of turn back to blue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, statusbar, android-statusbar

Our android app has blue color as colorPrimaryDark in resources which is responsible for status bar color. We are using a third party sdk for payment. Whenever we initiate that sdk it changes the color to red. And after completion of payment the status bar remains red. It might be caused by the changes in value of colorPrimaryDark.

Is there any way so that i can ovrride that colorPrimaryDark key whenever sdk stop doing it's work.

I tried to change in theme file.

Comment: What is the SDK?

Comment: A sdk is software development kit. In android people can build their own modules which can help people develop their app with less code. I our app we are using a third party sdk for payment interation.

Comment: Not "what is a SDK" but what 3rd party SDK are you using.

Comment: There is a payment gateway in india.Can't disclose the name but what i found that when that sdk initiates it has color red as colorPrimaryDark in resource file. Once its job done it closes by self. But status bar color remains red instead of turn back blue which if defined in my own resource file as colorPrimaryDark

Answer (score 0):

I guess the SDK which you use, are changing status bar color programmatically using your activity's `window` so the changed color remains even after the SDK stops.
you can use this code (in kotlin) to change the status bar color after the SDK is finished.

```kotlin
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200)
```

Place the above code where you are sure the SDK is finished. (based on SDK's documents)